# How to select from mysql array text and compare

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, text, pdo

I am collecting user selected "text" as array in mysql using PDO connection from php form there are let suppose 3 check boxes with names
1- Apple
2- Banana
3- Cherry

> In DB stored values are as per shown 
>   apple,banana,cherry
>
> What i want : I want to display "Apple" users in certain "/offer.php" page
>   while i am using SELECT query and it's not working i am using pure php mvc framwork.
>
> In Controller i done this

```
public function offer(){    
$this->view->title = User Selection;
$this->view->offerUser = $this->model->offerUser();
$this->view->render('dashboard/offer');
}
```

> In Model I done this

```
public function offerUser()
{
return $this->db->select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE selection = apple ORDER BY points DESC ');
}
```

> In View i done this

```
<?php
foreach($this->offerUser as $key => $value) {?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><strong><?php echo $value['selection']?></strong></td>
</tr>
```

> The issue is i am not able to select "Text" from stored array with model and even not able to display selection in "View" user end page.

This code format was working fine with single numeric digit selection or compare but failed with text array.

Please help me out with this i really appreciate this i am new with text array fetching.

Hope someone answer my question soon....

Regards,
james

Comment: wrap 'apple' in single quotes in you sql where clause

Answer (score 1):

query is not working : use single quotation around apple

```
public function offerUser()
{
 return $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE selection = 'apple' ORDER    BY points DESC ");
}
```

Comment: mate i try this i changed apple to 'apple' but when i run my app stop worked... any other solution you know for this....

Comment: use this: return $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE selection = 'apple' ORDER    BY points DESC ");

Comment: Yup this time it worked :) but i can't able to see records in front end page need changes here to                                                                                  <td><strong><?php echo $value['selection']?></strong></td> something wrong in view section

Comment: Why not you helped me with query correction i will vote for sure, the truth is didn't found any button for vote here because i am new here can you navigate me through,

Comment: The issue seems solved 50% and remaining 50% still left can you help me with that too...

Comment: i am not sure... but try this....replace "foreach($this->offerUser as $key => $value) {" --with-- "while($value=mysql_fetch_assoc($this->offerUser)) {"

Comment: i tried this too but still left this <td><strong><?php echo $value['selection']?></strong></td> until we define output we cannot see results take a look at your convenience.

Comment: is this true ?<td><strong><?php echo $value['selection']?></strong></td>